# while loop does not work in function php , global fix of ather

Tags: php, mysql

The while loop works fine in this example.

```
        $query="SELECT * FROM `ex`"; 
        $result=mysqli_query($link, $query); 

        $Q_X='Q1';
                    $res=array(0,0,0,0,0);
                while($report=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    print_r($report[$Q_X].'<br>');

                    if($report[$Q_X]=='X1'){
                        $res[0]=$res[0]+1;

                    }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X2'){
                        $res[1]=$res[1]+1;

                    }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X3'){
                        $res[2]=$res[2]+1;

                    }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X4'){
                        $res[3]=$res[3]+1;

                    }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X5'){
                        $res[4]=$res[4]+1;
                    }
                }
    list($Q1_1,$Q1_2,$Q1_3,$Q1_4,$Q1_5) = $res; 

    echo $Q1_1.',';
    echo $Q1_2.',';
    echo $Q1_3.',';
    echo $Q1_4.',';
    echo $Q1_5;
```

but when I try to put it in a function in doesn't work

```
        $query="SELECT * FROM `ex`"; //new
        $result=mysqli_query($link, $query); 

            function count_vote($Q_X) {
                $cont=0;

                global $result;  //new

                $res=array(0,0,0,0,0);
                while($report=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                    if($report[$Q_X]=='X1'){
                        $res[0]=$res[0]+1;

                    }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X2'){
                        $res[1]=$res[1]+1;

                    }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X3'){
                        $res[2]=$res[2]+1;

                    }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X4'){
                        $res[3]=$res[3]+1;

                    }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X5'){
                        $res[4]=$res[4]+1;
                    }
                }
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==$cont){
                return $res;
                }
            }


    count_vote("Q1");
    list($Q1_1,$Q1_2,$Q1_3,$Q1_4,$Q1_5) = $res; 

    echo $Q1_1.',';
    echo $Q1_2.',';
    echo $Q1_3.',';
    echo $Q1_4.',';
    echo $Q1_5;
```

I using an array to get multiple values returned

and if to prevent the function from exiting before the while loop ending

I am trying to make it into a function to use it multiple times on  Q1,Q2,..

can someone help me find the problem

---

```
              Q1  .  Q2  .  Q3  .  Q4
```

---

```
  user1  |    X1  .  X3  .  X5  .  X4

  user2  |    X2  .  X2  .  X3  .  X2

  user3  |    X1  .  X1  .  X1  .  X1
```

I want to get this resort

```
 Q1---> X1 >2
   ---> X2 >1
   ---> X3 >0
   ---> X4 >0
   ---> X5 >0

 Q2---> X1 >1
   ---> X2 >1
   ---> X3 >1
   ---> X4 >0
   ---> X5 >0
 Q3,Q4....
```

while loop does not work in function php

---

```
  list($Q1_1, $Q1_2, $Q1_3, $Q1_4, $Q1_5) = count_vote($result ,"Q1");

  echo $Q1_1 . ',';
  echo $Q1_2 . ',';
  echo $Q1_3 . ',';
  echo $Q1_4 . ',';
  echo $Q1_5 . '<br>';


  list($Q2_1, $Q2_2, $Q2_3, $Q2_4, $Q2_5) = count_vote($result ,"Q2");

  echo $Q2_1 . ',';
  echo $Q2_2 . ',';
  echo $Q2_3 . ',';
  echo $Q2_4 . ',';
  echo $Q2_5 . '<br>';
```

does not work ,it gives

2,1,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0

insed of

2,1,0,0,0

1,1,1,0,0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
function count_vote($result ,$Q_X)
{
    $res = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    while ($report = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($report[$Q_X] == 'X1') {
            $res[0] = $res[0] + 1;

        } elseif ($report[$Q_X] == 'X2') {
            $res[1] = $res[1] + 1;

        } elseif ($report[$Q_X] == 'X3') {
            $res[2] = $res[2] + 1;

        } elseif ($report[$Q_X] == 'X4') {
            $res[3] = $res[3] + 1;

        } elseif ($report[$Q_X] == 'X5') {
            $res[4] = $res[4] + 1;
        }
    }
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        return $res;
    }
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM `ex`"; //new
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

list($Q1_1, $Q1_2, $Q1_3, $Q1_4, $Q1_5) = count_vote($result ,"Q1");

echo $Q1_1 . ',';
echo $Q1_2 . ',';
echo $Q1_3 . ',';
echo $Q1_4 . ',';
echo $Q1_5;
```

I think the problem may be with the fact that the `$result` in the function was an empty global so we'll send that with the constructor as well.

Comment: it gives `Function name must be a string`

Comment: @MoazMabrok I made a typo, remove the dollar sign in front of `count_vote("Q1");`

Comment: Now it gives `0,0,0,0,0` instead of the numbers like 2,1,0,0,0 for Q1

Comment: You can try as like $count_res = count_vote("Q1"); list($Q1_1,$Q1_2,$Q1_3,$Q1_4,$Q1_5) = $count_res; And you are missing ot increase the value of $cont. So you have put $cont++ inside the  while loop.

Comment: @MoazMabrok I've made an update, let me know if it works.

Comment: @bucketman you are missing to increase the value of $count. You need $count++ inside the while loop.

Comment: @BilasSarker there is no count variable to increase and a `while` loop will iterate over each item once by itself. Is there something else you are referring to that needs to be incremented?

Comment: Here if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == $cont), So you need increasing the value of $cont in while loop. Sorry for $count actually it will be $cont.

Comment: @BilasSarker You weren't entirely wrong but it was easier to just remove the variable altogether and just type: `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` so I've made some further edits.

Comment: it works but   `  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {
        return $res;
    }` what is it for and `$cont++` is not used

Comment: @MoazMabrok look at the most recent version. `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` is correct. It checks if any rows are returned at all, otherwise it will not try to give you any results because there are none.

Comment: it works for one but if I use it more than one time the rest 0,0,0,0,0

Comment: @bucketman what is the problem it works for the first one only

Answer (score -1):

you've made a silly error. You have not incremented $cont. i.e.,

```
$cont=0;
```

Then you have checked:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==$cont){
  return $res;
}
```

So, this condition is never met as number of rows in $result is always more than 0. So, I think your revised code would be:

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM `ex`"; //new
    $result=mysqli_query($link, $query); 

        function count_vote($Q_X) {
            $cont=0;

            global $result;  //new

            $res=array(0,0,0,0,0);
            while($report=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                if($report[$Q_X]=='X1'){
                    $res[0]=$res[0]+1;

                }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X2'){
                    $res[1]=$res[1]+1;

                }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X3'){
                    $res[2]=$res[2]+1;

                }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X4'){
                    $res[3]=$res[3]+1;

                }elseif($report[$Q_X]=='X5'){
                    $res[4]=$res[4]+1;
                }
                $cont++;  
            }
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==$cont){
            return $res;
            }
        }


count_vote("Q1");
list($Q1_1,$Q1_2,$Q1_3,$Q1_4,$Q1_5) = $res; 

echo $Q1_1.',';
echo $Q1_2.',';
echo $Q1_3.',';
echo $Q1_4.',';
echo $Q1_5;
```

I hope it helps.